# Matlab error limitin bounds

Tags: matlab

I get the following error when I try to run this code "Attempted to access id(90); index out of bounds because numel(id)=89.Error in Untitled66 (line 26) person = find(id(fileNum)==ids);" Can someone help me spot the error?

```
% File Names reading and label generation 

dataFolder= 'allcontent/';
fileNames = dir([dataFolder 'c*.*']);

lbl = sscanf(cat(1,fileNames.name)','co2%c%d.rd_%d.mat');
status = lbl(1:3:end);
id = lbl(2:3:end);
ids = unique(id);
trial = lbl(3:3:end);

%% File reading and Data Generation 


%data = 256*channel*trial*stimulus*id
trData = zeros(256,64,10,3,20,'single');
label = zeros(10,3,20,'single');
trials = ones(3,20);

for fileNum = 1:numel(fileNames)

fin = fopen([dataFolder fileNames(fileNum).name]);
for i=1:4
line= fgetl(fin);
end
a= sscanf(line,'%S%d  %s , trial %d');
stimulus = (3-numel(a));

person = find(id(fileNum)==ids);
trialNum = trials(stimulus, person);
label (trialNum, stimulus, person) = status(fileNum);
fprintf('%d %d %d\n', person,trialNum, stimulus);

for ch=1: 64
fgetl(fin);
curData = textscan(fin,'%d %s %d %f');
trData(:,ch,trialNum,stimulus,person) = curData{4};
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`for fileNum = 1:numel(fileNames)` iterates over all files, but you don't have an id for each file: `id = lbl(2:3:end);`.

It seems to me that you want to iterate only over 1/3 or the files?

```
for fileNum = 2:3:numel(fileNames)
```

It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish, though. Are files related in groups of 3? You're probably better off selecting files from their names before computing `id` and all the other support matrices.